# How to extract part of string after '*', '~', '-' or '#'

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, string, function

I have strings like this:

```
234/1-1
3345#5
11/2~10
6754*15
```

It needed only rightmost part of string after '-', '#', '~'or '*' . I figured how to extract when there is only one sign for example  '~' with **right** and **strpos**. Can I do that with all at once with field calculator?

Comment: Have you looked at regular expressions?  regexp_substr in the field calculator?

Answer (score 11):

**ArcGIS Method**

In field calculator switch the parser to Python and check the "Show Codeblock" box.

In the Pre-Logic Script Code box enter

```
import re
def splitField(inField):
    return  re.split('[-|#|~|\*]', inField)[1]
```

In the TEXT box enter

```
splitField(!nameofField!)
```

**QGIS Method**

Open Field Calculator and go to the Function Editor tab.

In the code pane enter

```
import re
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def splitField(inField, feature, parent):
    return  re.split('[-|#|~|\*]', inField)[1]
```

Click the load button.

Go to the Expression tab and enter

```
splitField("NAMEOFFIELD")
```

Set your output field.

Then click OK to run.

Comment: +1 Regular expressions can tackle the most challenging string manipulation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that I use Qgis... and I can't reach  how this script work in a qgis field calculator

Comment: I updated my answer with a method for QGIS.

Comment: No need for a custom function this works: `regexp_substr('11/2~10','[-|#|~|\*](.*)')` `regexp_substr` is a built in function.

Comment: Good to know, although I had to modify the statement to `regexp_substr('11/2~10','[-|#|~|\\*](.*)')` to get it to work with the asterisk.

Comment: Thank you Jacob F, your method work excellent! I was tried first with regexp_substr and problem with asterisk. Good to know for that modification. Thanks.

Comment: @draganche85 - Don't forget to click the green faded tick on the left-hand side of this answer to formally accept it as having solved your problem :)

Comment: Using your code as a starting point I modified it so that you can define the string and index value as part of the function like so; splitField("MYFIELD",'x',n) x being the desired string and y being the desired list index number (+- can be used for forward/backwards indexing). For details https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363695/adding-vaiables-to-python-functions

Answer (score 3):

Hmm not sure how to do it all at once but you can do it in a couple of steps. I made an example using the values you specified:

[image: Example]

---

1. First we need to replace all forward slashes with an underscore `_`, the reason for this will be explained in the next step. You can use the expression:

   ```
   replace( "name", '/', '_')
   ```

   [image: Field calculator to replace]

---

2. Now we can extract the strings after any non-ASCII symbols such as those you mentioned. We can do this a varierty of operations:

   - ***substr*** - returns a part of a string
   - ***strpos*** - return first matching position of a substring

   We will also use the special [regular expression operation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) `\\W` which matches any non-alphanumeric character (i.e. anything other than letters, numbers, `^` and `_`). This is why we needed to replace `/` with `_`. Combining all the above allows us to extract the string after a non-alphanumeric symbol:

   ```
   substr( "replace", strpos( "replace", '\\W+')+1, strpos( "replace", '\\W+'))
   ```

   [image: Field calculator to extract]

We also use `+1` because we do not want to include the non-alphanumeric symbol itself, only everything after it.

---

3. Result:

   [image: Result]

Comment: This was method I was thinking about, but I used Jacobs code which is shorter and work great with my data. Thank you on your answer.

Comment: @draganche85 - Most welcome but I also agree in that Jacob's answer is much better =)