# How do you add user variables to custom Python functions in QGIS Function Editor?

Tags: qgis, python, string

How do you add user input variables to a Custom Function created in Python in QGIS3.x. I found the below piece of code but need to modify it to control the string to split by and the index value to return.

```py
import re
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def splitField(inField, feature, parent):
    return  re.split('[-|#|~|\*]', inField)[1]
```

How do I make the search string and the list index a user controlled variable?

Comment: I edited both the question and the answer, is that more clear?

Answer (score 1):

Using the example

```
import re
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def splitField(inField, feature, parent):
    return  re.split('[-|#|~|\*]', inField)[1]
```

the "def splitField(inField, feature, parent)" section is where you need to define the variables by adding "variablename" separated by a ",", then using that variable name in the pythoncode. Using the example code it should look like this.

```
import re
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def splitField(inField, inString, listIndex, feature, parent):
    return re.split(inString, inField)[listIndex]
```

When you use this Custom Function in your Expression builder you will address the variable sin the order they are listed in the "def splitField(inField, feature, parent):" section of the code for example

```
splitField("MYFIELD",'MYSTRING',MYINDEX)
```

or

```
splitField('QGIS ROCKS!', 'S', -1)
```

Will return "!" for more information how this is used the links below are good resources.

My source;
https://madmanwoo.gitlab.io/foss4g-python-workshop/expression_functions/
https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/pdf/en/QGIS-3.4-PyQGISDeveloperCookbook-en.pdf